# OneToMany with @EmbeddedId and kundera

Tags: java, hibernate, cassandra, kundera

I have two class and I want to use OneToMany relation  with EmbeddedId 
(Im working with **kundera** framework)
my sensor entity class:

```
public class SensorEntitie implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private CompoundKey key;
    @Column
    private float temperature;
    @Column
    private float pressure;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="what I should to put here")
    private List<PieceEntitie> pieces;
}
@Embeddable
    public class CompoundKey
    {
        @Column 
        private String IdSensor;           
        @Column 
        private long date;           
        @Column(name = "event_time")
        private long eventTime;
```

my piece class entity

```
public class PieceEntitie implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Id
    private String IdPiece;
    @Column
    private double width;
    @Column
    private double height;
    @Column
    private double depth;
```

but how can i fill the blank in @JoinColumn

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution :
to use OneToMany relation with EmbeddedId, I should to declare **JoinColumns** and multiple of **JoinColumn**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "idsensor", referencedColumnName = "idsensor"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "date", referencedColumnName = "date"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "event_time", referencedColumnName = "event_time")
})
```

Comment: While in general mappedBy will work, there are circumstances where `@JoinColumns` is needed, such as where a composite key in one table is part of a primary key in another in a `@ManyToOne`.  It's a shame that JPA doesn't have support for that (or if it does I've not found that magic).

Comment: `@OneToMany`? with a `@JoinColumns` ?

Comment: @lealceldeiro, he uses [unidirectional one-to-many association](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html). But it's not efficient. [The best way to map a `@OneToMany` relationship with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do some following steps for fixing problem

1. Remove @JoinColumn you dont need to write that statement
2. Remove @OneToMany to created object
3. Bind @OneToMany with getter method as per my following code

> ```
>  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pieceEntitie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
>  fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
> ```

```
    public Set<PieceEntitie> getPieceEntitie() {
            return pieceEntitie; 
    }
```

Comment: I tried your solution, and I fixed some problems, but this doesn't change anything, my framework saves data into separate tables without any relationship between two tables, so I can't get for example all data which are associated to my sensor table